# Can't echo get_delete_post_link

Tags: plugin-development

I am using **custom post_type** and **inside the loop** I echo get_delete_post_link but there is nothing echoing.

```
<?php 
$wpquery = new WP_Query('post_type=myposts');
  if( $wpquery->have_posts() ) {
     while ($wpquery->have_posts()) : $wpquery->the_post();

        $id = get_the_ID();
        //just a test to see can I get post IDs and I get them
        echo $id; ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link($id); ?>">Delete</a>
        <?php endwhile; }
          wp_reset_query();?>
```

This is the output

```
<a href="">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the user logged in and is allowed to delete posts of this post type? There are three checks inside the `get_delete_post_link` function before anything starts happening:

```
if ( !$post = get_post( $id ) )
    return;

$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
if ( !$post_type_object )
    return;

if ( !current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) )
    return;
```

I'm wild-guessing it's the third check that's failing in your case. You can paste them into your code and replace `return;` with debugging code to see what's going on:

```
if ( !$post = get_post( $id ) ) {
    echo 'could not get post. ';
} else {
    echo 'got post. ';
}

$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
if ( !$post_type_object ){
    echo 'could not get post object. ';
} else {
    echo 'got post object. ';
}

if ( !current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) ){
    echo 'user does not have proper capability. ';
} else {
    echo 'user is ok to delete this post. ';
}
```

Comment: First check failed, second and third passed, BUT I forgot that I didn't use register_post_type function yet. After implementing it, get_delete_post_link echoes just fine. Funny thing is that now all three checks fail :) ty

Answer (score 1):

All I can see that might cause this [is the check for delete permissions](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L962).

```
if ( !current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) )
     return;
```

If your user doesn't have delete permissions for the post the function returns nothing.

There could also be a filter on `get_delete_post_link`.