# get_delete_post_link() inside Loop stubbornly returns nothing

Tags: loop, query, customization

I've built a membership site where users can post listings from the frontend, edit those, and ideally also delete them.

For the latter, I'd like to echo a "delete post" link to the frontend. The problem is that `get_delete_post_link()`.

So from this:

`$theID = get_the_ID(); // inside loop
echo $theID;
<a href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $theID, '', false ); ?> ">Delete This Post</a>`

I get:

`123 /* = $theID; */
<a href="_">Delete This Post</a>`

I tried the following things:

- passing only $theID as argument instead of the full three
- passing `$theID, '', true`
- ran checks as described in the answers here: [Can't echo get_delete_post_link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/cant-echo-get-delete-post-link)
- the problem occurs both when I'm logged in as admin and as normal user (with added capacities)
- I made sure the permissions for the custom post type are mapped correctly
- outside the loop it works, but not inside the loop (the codex says it can be done within the loop: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_delete_post_link).

Here's the loop I'm using:

```
  // arguments
  $arguments = array(
    'post_type'         => 'CustomType',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'author_name'     => $current_user->user_login
  );


  // query
  $the_query = new WP_Query($arguments);

  <?php wp_reset_query();    // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
          <?php if( has_term( 'custom_term', 'custom_taxonomy' ) ): ?>
               /* stuff happens here */
               /* get_delete_post_link() returns nothing */
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

I'm at the end of my wits with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. get_delete_post_link() Should work without parameters if you are using it inside the loop
2. I believe that you need to remove your wp_reset_query() that is placed before the if( $the_query->have_posts()..

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but they sadly didn't work. get_delete_post_link() does work without arguments, but only if I place it outside of the loop, i.e. right before <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on WP_DEBUG and checked your error log? If there is something not set up quite right with the CPT, you'll see something like:

```
"Notice: map_meta_cap was called incorrectly. The post type CustomType is not registered, so it may not be reliable to check the capability "delete_post" against a post of that type. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.4.0.) in /yourpath/wp-includes/functions.php on line XX"
```